# What are Cache Misses in Dynamic Programming, and How Can I Avoid Them?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I am new to dynamic programming and have come across the concept of *cache misses* when analyzing the efficiency of various **dynamic programming** algorithms.

Particularly, I have seen that optimizing code to avoid *cache misses* can help improve run-time.

What are cache misses, and how can I avoid them when writing dynamic programming algorithms?

Comment: If you are new to dynamic programming, optimizing caching strategies is not the best use of your time. In order to properly analyze caching behavior you will need a deep insight of the microarchitecture of the platform you are running on, some specialized software tools for profiling code in practice, etc. I would reserve investigation of caching behavior as a last resort for performance, after exhausting any easier optimizations that can potentially have bigger impact.

Comment: somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559342/what-is-a-cache-hit-and-a-cache-miss-why-would-context-switching-cause-cache-mi

Comment: You are diving into the deep end of the pool without first learning to swim. Also; most code doesn't actually need to care about caching behaviour. There are usually 10-100 other things impacting performance that you should be fixing first.

Comment: You avoid cache misses in dynamic programming pretty much the same way you avoid cache misses in all programming. Quoting Stroustrup: "don’t store data unnecessarily,
keep data compact, and
access memory in a predictable manner."

Comment: Just minimimize the number of cache lines accessed, understand how the memory of your program is laid out etc.